# Editing rules in Outlook 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sorting, rules

I have a list of 30 rules to sort incoming mail on my POP3 and IMAP accounts, and move them into relevant folders (or permanently delete the known spammers).

Such a large set of rules didn't happen overnight and it sorely needs tidying. Some senders are being sorted into inappropriate folders and some have (I think) been set up to sort into more than one folder (or something) - resulting in no sorting at all. The problem is there are probably well over 100 addresses being checked for and Outlook provides the clumsiest imaginable "editor" for working on these rules. For starters, it displays the names of the senders you are selecting for as their "user friendly" names rather than the email addresses, so even just looking at a names in a list is a multi-step process.

Exporting the rules is relatively simple, but results in a ".RWZ" binary file that only Outlook can use and only as an import. In other words - not editable in human-readable form.

Isn't it possible to export / import the details of a rule in plain text format? Surely? Alternatively is there a rules editor somewhere out there that is more usable than the absolutely horrendous one built in to Outlook that hasn't changed in three decades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better rules editor for Outlook has been a very demanded feature
for many years. It didn't happen yet, and might never happen.
There don't seem to be many alternatives.

I have only found the
[Power Rules Manager](https://www.sperrysoftware.com/Email-Tools/product/power-rules-manager/),
which is an add-in for Outlook, and which costs $59.95 with
a 14-day trial period.

Most people prefer to minimize to the limit their number of rules,
and opt to use searches instead, whenever possible.

Comment: I have also found [this online editor](https://fileproinfo.com/tools/editor/rwz), but I don't know if it really exists.

Comment: Does look like a clickbait and switch doesn't it. Thanks for your input.